# Loop becomes Infinite when System.out.println() is added

Tags: java, swing, for-loop, infinite, system.out

I am working on a Swing Ti-Tac-Toe variation game. In the AI class I have a function that takes the board and a piece `morpionType`. It loops through all the available spots `intersections` on the board and returns the number of intersections which yield game over. It was behaving oddly so I decided to print out a statement from within the for loop. When I do that the loop becomes infinite.

The code is inside the Event Dispatch Thread. I can't realistically post the whole project so here is the piece of code.

```
public ArrayList<Point> check4WinIn1(Board board, MorpionType morpionType)
{
    ArrayList<Point> winningIntersections=new ArrayList<>();
    int counter=0;

    for(Point intersection: board.listOfAvailableIntersections)
    {
        //System.out.println("Testing!!! Testing!!!!"); 
        if(board.check4GameOver(new Morpions(morpionType, intersection, board.morpionRadius, board.getGameCounter()))) 
        {
            winningIntersections.add(intersection);
            if(winningIntersections.size()==2)
                return winningIntersections;     
        }
    }

    return winningIntersections;
}
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: what is the exact error? what is the exact line you are printing out?

Comment: Please format the code, i.e. indent it, for human readability.

Comment: It's almost impossible that the System.out creates an endless loop. Are you sure that it ends? What happens if you put a System.out after the for loop?

Comment: Sounds more likely that check4WinIn1() is being called infinitely many times, and the print statement visualizes it.

Comment: I am printing out "testing!! testing!!!". When I remove the statement it ends, but I do not get the right result.  When the statement is placed after the for loop it works.

Comment: do a System.out.println("before loop!!! before loo[!!!);  before the loop to see it that also keeps on printing.

Comment: if the same thing happens when the statement is placed after the loop, it just means the method is being called multiple times.

Comment: Before the loop it works after the loop it works. I am not sure why this might be happening at all. The only thing closest to this I found was this [https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269174/questions-about-threadloop-not-working-without-print-statement]

Comment: what is the size of your list?

Comment: The list size  is 1598 at the time of the call to check4WinIn1. I am certain that it ends when System.out.println() is commented out. check4WinIn1 is being called in a for loop that loops through all the available intersections. For each loop it add a piece at that specific intersection to a copy of the board and passes that to check4WinIn1.

Comment: if the list has 1598 does that mean that you have 1598 intersections and your are calling check4WinIn1 1598 times. If this is true that for each of the 1598 times it will print 1598 times which is equal to 2,533,604. but it should stop after that.

Comment: @isaace My problem is that it does stop when the statement is not there. It takes approximately 4 seconds to complete the process of evaluating a position.

Comment: what do you mean that it stops?

Comment: You said "When I do that the loop becomes infinite" so I am asking is it printing more than 2,533,604 times?

Comment: Ok I am and idiot. The loop does stop it just takes a long long time. I am sorry people!! As you were! Thanks, everyone!

Comment: It takes a long long time because printing consumes time, it ends faster when not printing because it doesn't need to write it.

Comment: I did not think that printing would have such an effect. I will keep that in mind as I carry on. Thanks!